# Pandas multihirarchical grouping

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a multi hirarchical table, although not with a nested dependency. I hope my screenshot, clarifies what i mean by that:

```
print (df)
  Country   Type data
0     Ger     VW   oo
1     Ita  Skoda   kk
2     Ger  Skoda   oo
3     Ita     VW   ik
```

On top is a representation of my data, the bottom is the result I hope to achieve.The numbers are the total sums of occurances.

My next step is to visualize it.

Data Frame is called cleaned_df

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape and for `MultiIndex Series` add [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = df[['Country', 'Type']].melt(var_name='a', value_name='b').groupby(['a','b']).size()
print (s)
a        b    
Country  Ger      2
         Ita      2
Type     Skoda    2
         VW       2
dtype: int64
```

But for visualise should be better:

```
s1 = df.groupby(['Country','Type']).size()
print (s1)
Country  Type 
Ger      Skoda    1
         VW       1
Ita      Skoda    1
         VW       1
dtype: int64

s1.unstack().plot.bar()

s1.unstack(0).plot.bar()
```